# Bayes theorem definition confusing

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm reading through a lesson on Bayes theorem and I saw this slide:
[image]

How can `model & data` be `==` `(data | model) x P(model)`?

Does the `&` not imply multiplication? Otherwise it implies that `data` == `data | model`.

Comment: Here $(A|B)$ means event A happens conditional on the event B happens. $(A \& B)$ means both event $A$ and $B$ happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both equations are correct. First one is the definition of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) in terms of [joint probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution)

$
P(Y = y \mid X = x) = \frac{P(X=x\ \,\cap\, Y=y)}{P(X=x)}
$

What is incorrect, is calling it Bayes theorem, since it is just the definition of conditional probability.

The & sign is *not* multiplication, since in mathematics we do not use "&" to denote multiplication. It is what it is, it means probability of observing $X=x$ **and** $Y=y$ together. It leads to multiplication *only* when $X$ and $Y$ are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29).

Comment: Minor quibble.  It still doesn't *mean* multiplication, even when X and Y are independent (it still means and).  It just results in multiplication algorithmically when the probability of the conjunction event is calculated in case the events are independent.

Comment: @MatthewDurdy good point, I changed the wording.